# Laravel 8 Error Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::loadRoutesFrom()

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I installed jetstream and livewire. After installation I got this error

> Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::loadRoutesFrom(): Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\suo\webapp\vendor\laravel\jetstream\src/../routes/.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR')

I tried to clear cache using following command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

But it also shows many warnings and then this error

```
 Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
```

Couldn't find any working solution. Any idea?

Comment: [same issue, click here for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64000967/15535914)

Comment: @MohitMangukiya Yes that did help. Thanks